# Composing continuous functions on abs.cont R.V

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm wondering what are sufficient conditions I cas ask for a function $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ s.t given ab abs.continous R.V $X:\Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, the composition $ f \circ \Omega$ will remain an abs continous R.V .
Is it enough that f will be continous?

Comment: What do you mean by an 
absolutely cont. random variable?

Comment: there is non negative density  function $f_x(t)$ s.t the cummaltive distribution function of X is given by $ F_X(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f_X(t)$

Comment: I don't think your suggestion of $f$ continuous is sufficient, as even e.g. the composition of two absolutely continuous functions need not be absolutely continuous: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406796/composition-of-absolutely-continuous-function-on-mathbbr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a Borel set, then $\mathbb{P}\{F(X) \in A\}$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}\{f(X) \in A\} = \int_{F^{-1}(A)} f_{X}(x) \, dx.
\end{equation*}
Hence the question boils down to: when is it possible to change variables in the right-hand side of the expression above?

There is a somewhat well-known sufficient condition, though I haven't seen it written down formally anywhere.  Roughly speaking, if $F^{-1}(\{x\})$ is finite for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $F(X)$ has the following PDF:
\begin{equation} \label{E: perron frobenius density}
f_{F(X)}(y) = \sum_{x \in F^{-1}(\{y\})} \frac{f_{X}(x)}{|F'(x)|}.
\end{equation}

When $f$ is a $C^{1}$ diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$, this follows directly from the change-of-variables formula:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{F^{-1}(A)} f_{X}(x) \, dx = \int_{A} f_{X}(F^{-1}(y)) |(F^{-1})'(y)| \, dy = \int_{A} \frac{f_{X}(F^{-1}(y))}{|F'(F^{-1}(y))|} \, dy.
\end{equation*}

More generally, one can prove the following (e.g. using Sard's Theorem):

> If $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a piecewise $C^{1}$ map (i.e.
> $C^{1}$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$, where $D$ is a closed set with no
> accumulation points) with the property that $F^{-1}(N)$ is a Lebesgue
> null set whenever $N$ is a Lebesgue null set, then, for any random
> variable $X$ with absolutely continuous law, the random variable
> $F(X)$ also has absolutely continuous law given by \begin{equation*}
>  f_{F(X)}(y) = \sum_{x \in F^{-1}(\{y\})} \frac{f_{X}(x)}{|F'(x)|}.
>  \end{equation*}

The case where $F$ is piecewise constant shows that the assumption concerning null sets is necessary to get absolute continuity of the law of $F(X)$.  (If $F$ is piecewise constant with countable range, then $F(X)$ has a singular law.)

In ergodic theory, the operator $f \mapsto \sum_{x \in F^{-1}(\{y\})} \frac{f_{X}(x)}{|F'(x)|}$ is called the Perron-Frobenius transfer operator; that's where I encountered it first.  I've also seen this formula (which is clearly of interest elsewhere) in a probability book for electrical engineers.